# Replacing all occurences in a sheet full of excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

In an Excel sheets there is a ton formulas with references to another sheet:

e.g. the formulas in the first few cells are written out here:

```
           A                                           B

   1      '[Another sheet 11.xls]Grill'!BD19            ...
   2      '[Another sheet 11.xls]Grill'!BF129
   3      '[Another sheet 11.xls]Grill'!AD29
   4      '[Another sheet 11.xls]Grill'!KA123
   5      ...
```

Is there any general way of going about replacing "[Another sheet 11.xls]" with "".

The data was copied from another sheet to begin with hence the borked references. Is there any other way of telling excel to keep the references in the same sheet?

xD Namaste

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the [simple] answer:

Search and replace => on formulas

:)

Answer (score 5):

I may be oversimplifying, but can you not simply do a "Find and Replace"? Just hit CTRL-F. In the dialog box, click on the "Replace" tab and then you'll notice at the bottom in Excel 2007 that there's a "Look in: Formulas". That's what you want to find, as opposed to "Values" or "Comments".

Comment: Looks like you posted your answer at the same time as I did and you came to the same conclusion. Good stuff.

Comment: The shortcut for search and replace is `CTRL`+`H`. Yet, this is the simpliest answer though

Answer (score 2):

In Excel for Mac, the Find and Replace route listed above doesn't have an option of finding in formulas. You can still do it by clicking the formula tab and selecting show formulas. Once formulas are shown a normal find and replace will do the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Under Data tab, there is an option called "Edit link". Change source to the current workbook. This will work only if the current workbook has the same page name for referring to.